# Getting at data in a file

Tags: c#, xml

Okay, silly question here, but I'm just starting with xml.

```
<fifth points = '500' answer = 'Ada Lovelace'>
    This woman, known as the world's first computer programmer
    was also a Countess.
</fifth>
```

How exactly do I get at the data after Ada Lovelace?  I understand that fifth is the node, and that points and answer are the attributes.  What must I grab to get the desired data?

Comment: since you are starting out with XML perhaps you would like to read this helpful link as well I find it to be a good learning resource myself http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
node.InnerText
```

To learn about parsing nodes XML in C#, read up on http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/ . This post, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7718/Using-XML-in-C-in-the-simplest-way may also be helpful as well, as it provides some of the simplest ways of parsing XML in C#.

You can simply index XmlNode with the node name: xmlNode["FirstName"].InnerText. See the example below.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
// suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>":
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString); 

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
  string lastName = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

The output is:

> Name: John Smith Name: James White

**Edit:** It's important to note that DJ KRAZE and Jeremy Thompson also inspired my answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is something you can try and test to help you understand how to get at the node.InnerText

```
var testDoc =
    @"<fifth points = '500' answer = 'Ada Lovelace'>"
       +  "This woman, known as the world's first computer programmer "
       +  "was also a Countess."
       + "</fifth>";
XmlDocument docXML = new XmlDocument();
docXML.LoadXml(testDoc);
var innerxml = docXML.InnerText;
MessageBox.Show(innerxml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). If this is a full xml you need to parse:

```
var xml = "<fifth points='500' answer='Ada Lovelace'>This woman, known as the world's first computer programmer was also a Countess.</fifth>";
XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);
string text = (string)element; // takes element's innerText
```

If you need to select this element from your xml file by answer attribute value:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml_file);
string text = xdoc.Descendants("fifth")
                  .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("answer") == "Ada Lovelace")
                  .Select(e => (string)e)
                  .FirstOrDefault(); // returns first matched element or null
```